# Trying to exclude procedure codes from the data

Tags: sas

I am trying to exclude procedure codes from the data:

```
Excludes antipsychotic meds (Long-Acting Injections) dispensed
DATA CLMSPULL_NEW2;
SET CLMSPULL_NEW;


Excludes hospice codes
DATA CLMSPULL_NEW3;
SET CLMSPULL_NEW2;
```

These are the codes built into macros:

```
/*Exclusions*/
%LET HOSPICE = 
        ('99377','99378','G0182','G9473','G9474','G9475','G9476',
        'G9477','G9478','G9479','Q5003','Q5004','Q5005','Q5006','Q5007','Q5008','Q5010','S9126','T2042',
        'T2043','T2044','T2045','T2046','0143', '0144', '0149', '0150', '0151', '0152', '0153', '0154', 
        '0159', '0160', '0164', '0167', '0169', '0200', '0201', '0202', '0203', '0204', '0206', '0207', 
        '0208', '0209', '0210', '0211', '0212', '0213', '0214', '0219', '0720', '0721', '0722', '0723', 
        '0724', '0729', '0987', '99221','99222','99223','99231','99232','99233',    
        '99238','99239','99251','99252','99253','99254','99255','99291');

    /*Long-Acting Injections*/  
%LET LAINJ = ('J0401','J1631','J2358','J2426','J2680','J2794');
```

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: YEs, I'm trying to create data sets where I exclude the long acting injections and the hospice codes.  Is my set up correct?

Comment: it is very unclear what you want to ask

Comment: What's the question, that's unclear, so we don't know what answer you're looking for here at all? 'is something correct' a really bad question because the answer is - it depends on your data, and set up most likely.

Comment: Answered here: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Excluding-codes-from-data-sets/m-p/465739

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you're asking, but here's an attemp, assuming you have in your dataset the two columns `hospice` and `lainj`:

```
proc sql;
  create table CLMSPULL_cleaned as
    select * 
      from CLMSPULL_NEW
     where hospice not in &hospice
       and lainj not in &laing;
quit;
```